# Using htaccess to set handling page for ALL address accessed on domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am building a php site framework and there are a couple of things that I would like to add in out of the box but they are going to need to be handled by .htaccess

**UPDATED:**

I am so close to getting this working perfectly.

```
RewriteEngine on
#this rule removes www from the URL if its used
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#this rule handles the subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+)\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php[L]

#this rule handles redirecting all addresses to index.php
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

That is all working now it handles the subdomains and all paths at the address bar.

The one thing that is occuring now though is that if I try to access a file directly for example css/master.css with an absolute path then it loads index.php instead.

Is there a tweak I can do to this to make sure if a file exists at the path that is does not redirect.

So close

Testing site.

http://something.rtbstats.com (404: as subdomain not there)

http://tracking.rtbstats.com (uses the index file from subfolder)

http://rtbstats.com (root)

http://rtbstats.com/home (loads homepage)

http://admin.rtbstats.com (pulls the admin area up)

I am only 1 level deep on the prettyURLs for this site but plan to build the admin area out to facilitate categories sub cats etc in the url path.

The admin area will even manage subdomains now with no need to access cpanel.

All of those different URLS are all handled by the .htaccess all I need now is to fix the absolute paths to files not working.

Comment: What about the dynamic loading of the domain to replace yoursite.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What about the dynamic loading of the domain to replace yoursite.com

Like this:

```
#this rule removes www from the URL if its used
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#this rule handles the subdomains
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+)\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/public_site/%1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I will test this in the AM and make sure all is good. Thanks!

Comment: Should this not be the rule based on the requirement set above. Just curious

#this rule handles the subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+)\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php[L]

Comment: @ukritic I don't know how `index.php` is handling everything, I just copied and pasted what you had

Comment: I have updated the question, with sample links it is almost working perfectly other than not getting css files properly. The way the htaccess is currently working when you try to link a css file it is loading index. All it needs now is to allow direct file access to files and we are golden. I am not an htaccess specialist so not sure on the syntax to achieve that. Thanks

Comment: @MadScientist You can exclude requests for files that exist by adding the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` condition, (see edit)

Comment: That did it, Thank you so much for that tweak. The whole thing works perfectly now!!!